# Auto slideshow loop with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How would I turn my swipe-able ViewPager into a auto looping slideshow? I'v read other post referencing to use a Handler or Timer but I'm not sure which one would be best. Iv posted my code below.

**Update:**

After following some old posts and comments Iv been trying to initiate a timer to loop through the ViewPager slides. The issue is now the Timer is not working, also not getting any errors either. Any thoughts? Iv added the Timer code to the MainActivity code below.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ViewPager viewPager;
customSwipeAdapter swipeAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    swipeAdapter = new customSwipeAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter);


    Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int currentPage = 0;
                    int NUM_PAGES = 3;
                    if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                        currentPage = 0;
                    }
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 500, 3000);


   }
  }
```

CustomSwipeAdapter.java

```
public class customSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private int [] image_resources = {R.drawable.SlideOne,R.drawable.SlideTwo,R.drawable.SlideThr,R.drawable.SlideFour};
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public customSwipeAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resources.length;

}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == (LinearLayout)object;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);

}
```

}

Comment: Using Timer should be Ok to me

Comment: Should the Timer be added in the MainActivity or CustomSwipeAdapter?

Comment: in `MainActivity`

Comment: Okay Ill try using a Timer then, Thanks!

Comment: Do, check the following library to have a auto slider effect along with page indicator dots and animations.   https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider